# UIImageView focus, fade background and zoom

Tags: ios, imageview

How would I go about making an image which I can tap which will trigger another view that has it zoomed and the other view slightly visible. Kinda like the twitter posting. I tap on the image, it fades to a transparent black, and in the middle is a larger version of the image I tapped on.

Answer (score 0):

Use a button with an image and use

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
.....
.....

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

To animate your views

Comment: the block-based animations are strongly recommended in iOS4+, instead of this way.